# How to make greedy regex for heading text? [as against tailing text]

Tags: regex

Consider the following text:

```
<bla><bla text><bla>
```

I want to get the regex to match exactly the middle `<bla text>`. I tried `\<.*?text.*?\>` but it is capturing the string right from the start, since it starts with '<'.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use code block for custom tags. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about

```
\<[^>]*text[^>]*?\>
```

Just not capture any character using `.`, capture anything but `>` using `[^>]*` before and after your "text".

See [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tpbv)

Comment: @Karthick, yes `\<[^>]*text.*?\>` will in your example work the same. You can easily play around with regexs on the page I linked, just change the regex and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

This regex matches the central `<bla text>` and captures it as the first match (brackets included):

```
(\<\w+? \w+?\>)
```

Explained, it matches:

- a `<`
- then, any non-empty sequence of word characters (`\w` is the shorthand for `[a-zA-z_]`)
- then exactly one space
- then another "greedy" sequence of word chars
- a final `>`

That is, it matches *exactly* two words separated by *exactly* one space, all enclosed in `<..>`.

This one:

```
(\<\w+?\s+\w+?\>)
```

also matches any number of spaces between the two words.

Finally, this one:

```
<\w+?>(\<\w+? \w+\>)<\w+?>
```

matches all the string, but captures the content of the central block, so that, if you want to replace the `<bla><bla text><bla>` string, you may refer to the central block using `$1` or `\1` in your replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your regexp.

```
/>(<bla.*?>)/
```